# Omitting a relative pronoun

Tags: relative-pronouns

> 1. It is not generally acceptable but sometimes reading a book difficult to understand is good to improve intellectual thinking.
> 2. It is not generally acceptable but sometimes reading a book that is difficult to understand is good to improve intellectual
>      thinking.

Which of the two sentences is correct ? (I wrote the sentences myself.)

Can I omit 'that is' in the sentence?

If not, could you please explain it clear why it does not make sense?

And I have heard about the rule that a subject-relative-pronoun cannot be reduced with the verb of its relative pronoun, could you tell me that for what reason the rule is made?

I assume that it be the reason to avoid misunderstanding meaning of a sentence, but I am not quite sure whether my assuming is correct or not.

Comment: The first two clauses *(It is not generally acceptable, but sometimes)* are syntactically irrelevant to the statement that follows. You could also discard the two syntactically irrelevant clauses *within* that statement, giving the basic construction ***Reading a book is good***. There's no place for a "relativising" ***that*** there unless you include the clause *Reading a book **that is difficult** is good*.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the "but sometimes"? That unnecessary bit is ruining your sentence and increasing the ungrammaticality. Note that saying "not generally accepted" *already states* the "sometimes" nature of the proposition.

Here is your sentence, without the "but sometimes" and cleaned up (note that I changed "acceptable" to "accepted":

> It is not generally accepted that reading a book that is difficult to understand is good for improving intellectual thinking.

If you're overly concerned about removing the "that is" from it:

> It is not generally accepted that reading a difficult-to-understand book is good for improving intellectual thinking.

You can cut it down even further:

> It is not generally accepted that reading a difficult book is good for improving intellectual thinking.

Or even:

> It is not generally accepted that reading a difficult book can improve intellectual thinking.

Comment: I think you've shifted the intent of the statement by switching from *not accepted **but*** to *not accepted **that***.

Comment: Sorry I have already edited the sentences before you answer my question. I should have looked over once again... (because a native speaker pointed out the errors), from 'It is not generally acceptable, but sometimes, that reading a book difficult to understand is good for improving intellectual thinking.' to 'It is not generally acceptable but sometimes reading a book difficult to understand is good to improve intellectual thinking.'

Comment: That's still bad. Just because someone is a native speaker doesn't mean they can write well.

Comment: I think the issue OP is trying to explore concerns the acceptability of discarding ***that is*** in constructions involving an "infinitive verb-based adjectival compound", such as *I only eat food [that is] easy to digest*. My position is that *in general*, it's not a good idea. In any case, we'd often relocate the adjectival element to come *before* the relevant noun, as *I only eat easy-to-digest food* (where the hyphens are to some extent optional, and represent a meaningless concept in speech anyway).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: So you would find fault with usage in the adage "A penny saved is a penny earned"?

Comment: Of course not, but perhaps that's because it's a "set phrase" construction. Which would allow, for example, *A fortune ill-gotten is a fortune despised*, but that would hardly license *I despise his fortune ill-gotten* (except in a floridly poetic context). You'd either include some kind of "relativiser" *(I despise his fortune **which is** ill-gotten)*, or you'd "front" the adjective *(I despise his ill-gotten fortune).*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: And, by the way, Shakespeare is full of such constructions, e.g., "'Tis a consummation devoutly to be wished" (from Hamlet's "To be or not to be" soliloquy);

Comment: Indeed. But I did mention "floridly poetic contexts" earlier. Querents on ELL often explicitly ask to be told about the *formal/informal* associations of any given usage - but even if they don't usually think to ask about possible ***poetic*** overtones, I'd say that's highly relevant information when you're trying to get to grips with a foreign language (especially one so thoroughly steeped in Shakespeare! :)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is

`It is **good to do** {something} (in order) to {achieve a goal}.`

> It is good to do stretching exercises in order to stay limber.

And we can make a general statement without explicitly mentioning the goal:

> It is good to do stretching exercises.

The predicate "it is good" is complemented by an infinitive construction:

It is good {TO DO {something} }

**to do {something}** is a subject that has gotten bumped out of subject position by so-called "dummy It".  It has been "extraposed". Here it is not extraposed:

> To do stretching exercises is good.

Your sentence follows the pattern at the top, which mentions a goal, and it would follow the pattern at the bottom, where the extraposed subject is made the actual subject, if it were not for the fact that it substitutes the gerund **reading** for the infinitive, **to read**.

But it has some extraneous material unrelated to the pattern which we can strike out for the sake of clarity and simplicity:

> <strike>It is not generally acceptable but  sometimes</strike> reading
>   a book <strike>difficult to understand</strike> is good to improve
>   intellectual thinking.

And let's replace **reading** with **to read**:

> To read a book is good to improve thinking.

And now let's extrapose the subject and use dummy It:

> It is good to read a book to improve thinking.

P.S. The clause **difficult to understand** is simply a modifier of **book**, *a book [which is] OR [that is] difficult to understand.*

> Books **hard to find** can be expensive.

Comment: You seem to have covered just about everything here. *Except...* it might be worth pointing out that (imho, at least) your final example would be more idiomatically expressed with the first adjectival element *before* the noun (as is normal with adjectives in general). Hyphenated or not makes no difference in speech, where I'd normally expect *Hard-to-find books can be expensive*.

Comment: *Books hard to find can be expensive* is to my AmE ear no less idiomatic  than *Hard-to-find books can be expensive*.

Comment: I'm more than a little surprised by that! Adjectival *hard-to-find* isn't all that common, so I didn't see any point in checking corpuses. But by implication I assume you's say the same about, for example, *Books well written are enjoyable.* As I said, I don't think hyphens are relevant, being just an orthographic convention that doesn't affect the actual *grammar*....

Comment: Fortunately, Google Books doesn't distinguish between punctuation marks and spaces anyway, so I searched for [*of well-written books is*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22of+well-written+books+is%22) and [*of books well-written is*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22of+books+well-written+is%22), which gave 56 hits for the former (the one I'd normally expect), and none at all for the "post-positioned adjective" in the second version (note that ***of*** and ***is*** areonly included in the search string to limit results to the syntactic context we're talking about here).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "Books well-written **is**" ?  But this is a colloquial pattern of speech, *and normally relates to a prior mention*, so I wouldn't expect a Google search to provide much in the way of useful information.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+road+less+traveled+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20road%20less%20traveled%20is%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Per previous comment, my reason for wrapping the "adjective + noun" (and "noun + adjective") string inside ***of + is*** was just that it's an easy way to screen out constructions like *Are his books well written?*, so we could focus on truly comparable instances of the two different positions for the adjectival element. As for the recent popularity of *The Road Less Traveled*, I think it's a somewhat quirky/poetic book title that doesn't really reflect normal syntax today. Google Books has over 500 hits for *a less well known case,* for example, but only 10 hits for *a case less well known*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Google Shmoogle. It's not dispositive here.  All I can say is that the reduced clause as postmodifier is perfectly well established in my own dialect of AmE.  I think your ear is being thrown off by the plural, **Books**.

Comment: *An idea slow to catch on is often a good one.*   *Tastes hard to achieve are what these new wave chefs are seeking.*

Comment: I'm intrigued by the fact that a usage which strikes me as stylised/poetic should seem so "natural" to you. In the end this might just be a matter of we two having different *personal* opinions, but in the pious hope that it won't just get closed as POB, I'm minded to ask about a possible US/UK usage split over on ELU. Will post a link if/when I do so.

Comment: I don't think it rises to the level of "poetical" or ornate language by any means, but I would concede that the post-placement puts some additional emphasis upon the modifier.

Comment: I raised [Phrasal adjective before/after noun. US/UK usage split?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/426623/phrasal-adjective-before-after-noun-us-uk-usage-split/426631#426631) over on ELU to explore this usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Re: *Of books well-written...* I would accept that it is very rarely used in comparison to the alternative. However one cannot gainsay that it is perfectly grammatical English, and available to any literate person to use - perhaps to achieve emphasis. Other examples sound even more plausible - *Students ill-prepared for a question on Edmund Burke, will be at a disadvantage*. Or, how about *Anyone ill- prepared...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers On a more general point, I'm not going to be guided by Google N-Grams as to how I speak English. The fact that millions of people say something differently to the way I have expressed it all my life, or the way it may have been expressed in the time of Chaucer, is no guide for me. You are unlikely to find *Nicholas then let fly a fart* in Google Ngrams, but it doesn't reduce its validity. I fear that if we go the Google route we shall have a colourless dumbed-down, profoundly monotonous dialogue.

Comment: @WS2: You're a native speaker, so obviously you don't need to be told how to speak! I just pointed out to the OP that his final example would be ***more idiomatically expressed*** with the first adjectival element before the noun. I used NGrams to conclusively prove that this is what most writers do. It looks like you're agreeing with Tᴚoɯɐuo above (he also thinks that "postmodified" *the road less travelled* isn't a particularly "poetic / literary" alternative to *the less travelled road*). But undeniably that form is far less common, regardless of whatever "register" it falls within.

Comment: @FumbleFingers By all means let's point out to non-native speakers the more idiomatic alternatives, but surely one of the reasons that generations of British children are encouraged to read Shakespeare, Milton, Jane Austen, Oscar Wilde, Hemingway, and GB Shaw among a thousand others is to familiarise them with a more elegant idiom than they are likely to find on Google NGrams. No harm in letting the non-natives in on the secret too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't know if you ever read [this paper on "The pitfalls of  Ngrams"](https://www.wired.com/2015/10/pitfalls-of-studying-language-with-google-ngram/).

Comment: @WS2: As a literary studies graduate, I'm all for promoting great literature. But the point I'm making about OP's *reading a book difficult to understand is good* and Tᴚoɯɐuo's *Books hard to find can be expensive* isn't about that. I'm simply making the point that although they're both syntactically valid, those are "unusual" usages best avoided by learners. Plus I'm sure most learners don't want to inadvertently end up speaking like characters from a Dickens novel just because nobody told them about differences between "poetic" and "natural" usages.

Comment: Windows smudged with soot are hard to see through.  I think you're being misled by the fact that "hard-to-find" has achieved adjective status in a way that "smudged with soot" has not.  "I'm looking for a hard-to-find book to give as a gift. Any damn book will do as long as it's rare!"  I'm looking for a book hard to find; do you have Johnson's "Life Among The Ganja Eaters"?   The adjective and the modifying clause can have subtly different meanings.  But the clausal version isn't "unusual".